# Set AndroidResource build action in Shared Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, shared-project

I have lots of shared resources (layout, drawable, etc) in my Xamarin.Android projects.  I want to have these shared resources in a centralized 'shared project'.  (I cannot use Xamarin Library project type for some reason.  'Shared project' is my only choice here).  However, the 'Build action' in shared project is limited to the following:

[image: default build actions]

Is there any chance to use the 'AndroidResource' build action here?

Comment: While it is technically possible to manually edit the `.shproj` and include a conditional `ItemGroup` that in turn defines `AndroidResource`, this can (and does) break various build features of Xamarin.Android (and things like the Forms previewer) as native build types are not expected to exist in shared projects.

Comment: I actually tried manually editing the shproj and adding <AndroidResource> tags.  As soon as Visual Studio opens the project, these resources files are 'excluded' from the project automatically.

Comment: Have you resolved your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I think it needs to be a feature improvement in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an Android Shared Project, you could use an Android Class Library. That will already include a Resources folder.

Comment: I have to use shared project in order not to deal with the complicated project dependencies of class library.